# how to play sound if condition came true javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program to calculate the mean of a numbered array , and i allow the user to enter his answer , i want to play (success sound) if the user answer equals the real answer , and play (error sound) if not.

```
function calcMean(){
...}

function solution(){
...
if(useranser==realanswer){
//play success sound by calling soundPlay()}
if(useranswer!==realanswer){
//play error sound  by calling soundPlay()}


function soundPlay(){
//somthing 
 }
```

I design the program in HTML not HTML5. I would like know how to load the audio file(the success sound) and then how i can trigger it to start playing once a user provides a correct answer.

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: i design a HTML page , with javascript .
i want to play a sound if the first condition yes , and another sound if the second condition yes ,
how ?

Comment: i mean how to get the sound and play it by calling the soundPlay() function

Comment: so basically, you are saying you want to see how to load an audio file, and play it, if the answer is correct? the original question is/vague!

Comment: yes yes,
espically i don't use HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Keep  a hidden audio player in your html page

```
<audio controls id="player" style="display: none">
<source id="player-src" src="#"></source>
</audio>
```

load the src dynamically and play it

```
function solution(){
if(useranser==realanswer){
 soundPlay("success sound src");
}
if(useranswer!==realanswer){
 soundPlay("error sound src");
}
}
function soundPlay(src){
var audioElement = document.getElementById('player-src');
audioElement.src =src ; //src for the player
var myAudio = document.getElementById("player");
myAudio.load();
myAudio.play();
}
```

Comment: i want somthing to use in HTML

Comment: <audio> tag is in HTML5 
i want sth in XHTML